nginx running on EKS gives 403 /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied)
I have a nginx pod running in EKS. The static content is stored in S3 which is mounted on the POD using s3.csi.aws.com driver as follows.
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: s3-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1200Gi # ignored, required
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany # supported options: ReadWriteMany / ReadOnlyMany
  mountOptions:
    - allow-delete
    - region us-east-1
  csi:
    driver: s3.csi.aws.com # required
    volumeHandle: s3-csi-driver-volume
    volumeAttributes:
      bucketName: bucket-XXXX-NAME

But when i try to access the localhost i get 403 error
curl http://localhost
2024/05/07 06:50:28 [error] 40#40: *2 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2024:06:50:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 153 "-" "curl/7.88.1" "-"

The nginx config is as follows :
  nginx.conf: |
    user nginx;
    worker_processes  auto;

        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
        pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;

            location / {
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            }
        }


        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;


        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    }


with a curl http://localhost should give me the index.html page.

I was able to fix this by changing the user nginx to user root in the config file as the nginx image runs the nginx process as root user.
